# Grails not using query cache in view

Tags: hibernate, grails

I've found an odd issue regarding the query cache in grails and where it's called.  I've tested this several times and got the same result.

**Problem:** The bellow view\gsp code hits the database every time even though i have `cache:true` on.

```
 <g:select name="foo.thing.id" in="${Thing.findAll([cache:true])}" value="${foo.thing?.id}" />
```

**Workaround:** Pushing the query call into the controller respects the `cache:true` argument and it now stops hitting the database on every page load.

Controller:

```
def doStuff = {
  def things = Thing.findAll([cache:true]);
  return ['things':things]
}
```

View:

```
<g:select name="foo.thing.id" in="${things}" value="${foo.thing?.id}" />
```

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 with the following config....

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
```

**Has anyone else seen this or can describe to me why it would work differently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but this is Grails, not PHP - don't do database access in the view.

Comment: Strongly Agree. It is definitely a bad practice. The main reason behind MVC architecture is separation of concern.